# Integration question in connection with two types of centroid

Tags: integration, geometry

I came across a question while researching characteristics of surfaces and
solids of revolution.  In the standard coordinate plane, consider a general
simple open curve C in the half plane above the x-axis, with its two endpoints
on the x-axis.  Denote by "wire centroid" the centroid of the curve C, and by
"lamina centroid" the centroid of the two-dimensional closed area A delimited
by C and the x-axis.  Both C and A are assumed to have uniform density.  It
seems intuitive that the y-coordinate of the wire centroid will always be
greater than that of the lamina centroid since all of the "mass" of C is
concentrated along the upper edge of A, while the mass of A is spread out
uniformly throughout its area.

Specifically, can the following be proven for general parametric functions x(t)
and y(t) tracing out C over t $\in$ T?

$$\text {Wire centroid y-coordinate} > \text {Lamina centroid y-coordinate}$$

$${\int_T\ y(t)\sqrt{[x'(t)]^2 + [y'(t)]^2} dt \over \int_T\
\sqrt{[x'(t)]^2 + [y'(t)]^2} dt} > {\int_T\ [y(t)]^2 x'(t) dt \over 2 | \int_T\
x'(t) y(t) dt |}$$

If there's a formal term known for "wire centroid", please provide a reference.

Comment: A more intuitive terminology may be to use "area centroid" for the lamina
centroid, and "edge centroid" for the other one (which excludes the x-axis part
of the outline of A).  A counterexample to the original question is a
near-triangular isosceles trapezoid of height 24, with its shorter base of 1 on
the x-axis and its longer base of 15 above it.  Its area centroid ordinate is
$Y_A$ = 2976/192 = 15.5, which is larger than its edge centroid ordinate of
$Y_E$ = 960/65 = 14.77.

Comment: Previous comment, continued

However, if it's further stipulated that A is convex and C is defined by a
function of x (so that its solid of revolution about the x-axis is convex), is
the original question $Y_E$ > $Y_A$ true?